# What to do if my NVidia 4090 Laptop GPU has an invalid device ID?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia

I have an **Alienware M18 R1** with an i9-13980hx, and a **NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU** that I bought a few months ago. It worked great for a while.

Background: *Recently I started getting BSODs that I tried working around in various ways, related to the CPU, finally resulting in a **motherboard replacement** that was installed yesterday.
The technician noted that one of the screws near the CPU was not tightened at all, likely resulting in inadequate cooling for the components around the CPU (the CPU core temps were fine, but obviously I couldn't measure the voltage regulator etc. temps).
The **new motherboard passed all tests** and booted into Windows 11 just fine.*

However, I have quickly noticed in Windows Device Manager that instead of my GPU, I have a "**Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.**"
I tried everything to fix it: Uninstalling that adapter, DDU, DDU in safe mode, installing the manufacturer (Dell) NVidia driver, installing the latest NVidia drivers from the website.
When trying to install drivers, I would very quickly get the following error message:

- Dell/Alienware (slightly older) NVidia Graphics Driver installer: "*This NVIDIA graphics driver is incompatible with this version of Windows. This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware*."
- Official NVidia 546.01 Graphics Driver installer: "*NVIDIA Installer cannot continue: This NVIDIA graphics driver is incompatible with your device. The correct driver can be downloaded from NVIDIA.com/drivers by selecting correct product information. This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware.*"
- *(I also tried the NVidia desktop drivers - same error.)*

Now, I immediately thought the new motherboard has a faulty GPU *(the screen worked since it was on the integrated Intel GPU)*, so I scheduled another motherboard replacement.
Note that I tried to run GPU-Z and it showed a "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" as my GPU, but it was showing a bunch of correct stats for a 4090 GPU, like the technology (5nm), fillrates, etc.
So it was clearly there, just inaccessible.

Next, I tried to install and run Ubuntu from a USB stick.
After installing all the drivers, including the closed-source NVidia drivers, **the GPU worked perfectly**, automatically without any custom configuration, as if nothing is wrong.
I even installed Steam, and ran a relatively modern videogame to utilize the GPU, Dota 2, without any issues.
(At 1440p at all max settings I had 200fps in Dota 2, and the Ubuntu NVidia tool was showing the GPU was changing to higher frequency settings, so I was sure it wasn't using the built in Intel GPU.)

Then I tried installing a separate clean copy of Windows 11 to a USB drive, using Rufus, as a "Windows To Go" installation.
Again, I had the same exact issue: a "**Microsoft Basic Display Adapter**", and the same error messages shown when trying either of the two NVidia drivers that I mentioned earlier.

Then I tried something a bit unusual, I booted back into my main Windows 11 install and tried to manually to "**Update Driver**" by extracting the latest official NVidia drivers into a directory,
and then using "**Have Disk**" and pointing it to the directory of "(base dir)\DisplayDriver\546.01\Win11_Win10-DCH_64\International\Display.Driver".
This showed a bunch of various GPUs, including about between 5-10 "**NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU**" entries (my GPU model), so I just picked the first one (I'm not sure if there is any difference between them).

**This somehow fixed the issue: the NVidia drivers were installed (including tools such as NVidia Control Panel), my second monitor suddenly sprung to life,**
the Alienware Command Center could now detect a GPU and show its stats, and I could normally run Dota 2 as well as 3DMark
(although [3DMark Time Spy is showing a score of about 17.9k](https://www.3dmark.com/3dm/102337320) compared to about 20k with the old motherboard, but that is probably unrelated; also, I disabled Optimus so I'm only using the NVidia GPU).

So then I figured, maybe there is some issue with my device identifier such that the drivers cannot recognize it?

In fact, this is what is shown for my device ID in Windows and GPU-Z:

- Windows: PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_2757&SUBSYS_0C481028&REV_A1
- [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/details/z52pu): 10DE 2757 - 1028 0C48

Grepping the NVidia .inf files shows that there is **no perfect match for that ID**.
The closest match is in the file nvdmig.inf:

```
$ grep "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU" *.inf | egrep 2757 | egrep 1028
nvdmig.inf:NVIDIA_DEV.2757.0BF0.1028 = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU"
nvdmig.inf:NVIDIA_DEV.2757.0BFC.1028 = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU"
nvdmig.inf:NVIDIA_DEV.2757.0BFE.1028 = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU"
nvdmig.inf:NVIDIA_DEV.2757.0C49.1028 = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU"
nvdmig.inf:NVIDIA_DEV.2757.0C4B.1028 = "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Laptop GPU"
```

Note that my ID is:

- NVIDIA_DEV.2757.0C48.1028, while the closest match that is actually in the file is:
- NVIDIA_DEV.2757.0C4B.1028

It's almost the same, **except there is a difference in the "8" as shown for my actual device, and "B" in the file.**

So far the GPU works <s>perfectly</s> fine (based on my limited testing today), although I'm not sure if I will be able to update my drivers without having to do the "Have Disk" procedure every time.
Maybe I can somehow fix the Device ID myself? :)

**[EDIT] Games like Cyberpunk 2077 don't seem to detect the GPU properly, so they don't allow using modern RTX features like DLSS. This is certainly a big problem.**

So I'm left to wonder:

1. did someone somehow change the Device ID of this refurbished laptop motherboard? Maybe they were putting in a device ID by hand and made a mistake in the "8" vs "B"?
2. is it even possible to change the physical Device ID?
3. or maybe I have some unique GPU 4090 sample that left the factory like this?
4. is there a difference between the identically-named GPUs in the Windows "Have Disk" list?
5. is there any way I can fix the missing DLSS issue for games like Cyberpunk 2077?

Thanks!

**[EDIT] Final update: I have a replacement GPU which has a correct Device ID so I no longer have this problem.**

*TLDR: The NVidia 4090 Laptop GPU from a replaced motherboard for my Alienware laptop has a Device ID that doesn't exist in either the offical, or laptop manufacturer, GPU drivers. Manually selecting the GPU from a list using an .inf file makes it work in Windows. However, it "just works" in Ubuntu. Why is my Device ID wrong and is there a way to fix it?*

[image: GPU-Z]
[image: NVidia Installer]
[image: Windows GPU details]
[image: Cyberpunk DLSS not working]

Comment: Unfortunately the only solution is to replace the motherboard or if you feel comfortable with the skill of the technician have them replace the soldered GPU, but that is most definitely, not a guaranteed solution (removing and soldering the Nvidia GPU). The drivers absolutely should be identifying the GPU. OEM mobile Nvidia drivers for the 400 series isn’t a thing. Impossible to determine the reason it’s wrong with the information you provided

Comment: Thank you - I already have a support request for another motherboard replacement. Hopefully the 3rd one will be the lucky one.

Comment: It's possible that the Dell support pages have a customised driver for your GPU. Have you checked there? https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/alienware-m18-r1-laptop/drivers

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything on the list that mentions "nvidia" or "geforce". Basically, there's a repackaged older version of the nvidia drivers, the results of trying it are explained in the question. I've also tried grepping the .inf files in the "Dell" driver package, and I reached the same conclusion as for the official drivers regarding the Driver ids. I've also tried using the Alienware update tool, etc.

Comment: Was it an official repair partner replacing the mainboard? Do all GPU details match a 4090? Right now this feels as if the device ID is forged to sell a way cheaper board as something more expensive, while botching the ID by misspelling a Latin character (which wouldn't be new for someone uneducated from China or India).

Comment: Yes an official Dell partner rep replaced the motherboard in my apartment, I was in the room with the tech and everything seemed to be above board. All the GPU details match a 4090. Yeah I wonder if that's the case too. In any case, I doubt it was the tech, maybe a "bad" replacement motherboard itself came into Dell's posession by mistake somehow. They did say the replacement was a refurb. In any case, thanks!

Comment: have you tried cleaning out all traces of NVIDIA drivers with DDU uninstaller and then rebooting into safe mode and try installing the nvidia driver in safe mode. Seems like an odd suggestion i know but it worked for me on a seperate compatibility issue i had with a GPU in win10 before.

Comment: Yes, that's a good suggestion, in addition to trying the drivers in normal mode, I also tried installing them in safe mode too but that had the same results. Thanks.

Comment: The device id is correct: [Device Hunt](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/pci/vendor/10DE/device/2757) names the device "GN21-X11", which according to [Tech Power Up](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-4090-mobile.c3949) is indeed the "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 Mobile". NVIDIA says that the driver is [546.01 - WHQL](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/results/216399/). If this is indeed your driver, I suggest asking NVIDIA Support about their installation problem.

Comment: Right, 10DE is NVidia, and 2757 is the 4090 Laptop GPU, however for the drivers to recognize the GPU, the "SUBSYS" part (0C481028) must match too. In the .inf files, there are various combinations of those 8 hex characters, but none that match my GPU exactly, therefore the NVidia drivers (or Windows) don't recognize them. Only when I manually "force install" the drivers, bypassing the Device ID check, they "work". However, certain games like Cyberpunk 2077 don't allow DLSS to work when using this "force install" method. I will try NVidia support, thanks!